# Weighted overlay for polygon data

Tags: arcgis-pro, weighted-overlay

So you know there's a `[Weighted Overlay][1]` tool that return indexed raster based on classed/indexed raster that have been assigned weights totaling to `100`. Now I want to do the same thing but for `census tract` polygons. Basically, I have values for four variables for each census tract. I have standardized (using the `Standardize` tool) all four variables on a scale of `1-5`.

What exact next steps I can do to calculate a result similar to the `Weighted Overlay` tool in ArcGIS Pro 3.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out (I would still appreciate feedback):

Approach 1:

```
A = Multiply each variable's 1 value to a weight
B = Multiply each variable's 2 value to a weight
C = Multiply each variable's 3 value to a weight
D = Multiply each variable's 4 value to a weight

The add i.e. A + B + C + D
```

Approach 2:

Don't standardize the variable values
Use them as is in the `Identify Community Characteristics` tool which will return a polygon feature class with a rank score.

Approach 3:

Standardize the variables using the `Standardize Field` tool and then just them to get an index.